# What's the equivalent of the php Laravel's "Http::fake()" in Python/ Django / DRF / Pytest?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests, http-mock

Laravel's `Http:fake()` method allows you to instruct the HTTP client to return stubbed / dummy responses when requests are made. How can I achieve the same using Django Rest Framework `APIClient` in tests?

I tried `requests_mock` but it didn't yield the result I was expecting. It only mocks requests made within test function and not anywhere else within the application or project you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can use import the fixture `admin_client` and then do requests like this:

```
def test_get_project_list(admin_client):
    resp = admin_client.get("/projects/")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == {"some": "thing"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of Laravel's `Http::fake()` in Django is `requests_mock`.

- You must user python `requests` module to call external apis
- Then user `requests_mock` to fake external APIs

The mocker is a loading mechanism to ensure the adapter is correctly in place to intercept calls from requests. Its goal is to provide an interface that is as close to the real requests library interface as possible.

Let me know if you need me to post an example.

You can read more from the [requests mock module official website](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html)